# Does a refrigerator need to be run periodically to stay in working order?

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, storage

Last time a refrigerator failed on me, I ended up paying several hundred dollars extra because I needed a fridge NOW.

This time, I replaced it when it seemed to be running too high a percentage of the time. The replacement took 4 weeks to arrive.

I would like to keep the old one, for the next time a fridge fails on me.  (I live rurally)

Does the fridge need to be run periodically -- say turn on for an hour every two months to keep oil on the compressor vanes, keep bearings from freezing, etc.

Comment: "running at a higher duty cycle" could be **anything**. The #1 culprit is leaky door gaskets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your old fridge runs for much higher percentage of the time, chances are:

- it has either partially lost its working substance ("freon")

or

- its insulating foam has degraded way too much.

Contrary to the popular belief, the compressor degradation is unlikely to contribute. Modern (post-1980) fridge compressors generally fail at once.

Both failure modes (esp. the gas leak) tend to progress with time and don't much depend on usage. The most probable outcome is that after few months it will not work at all.

Of course, your mileage may vary and here comes the periodic test.

In other words, the fridge may be OK or not independent of you powering it on once in a while, but starting it once in a while may help you decide what to do next.

Comment: Freon has been banned since 1987. Unless you have a very old fridge, the working substance will be some other gas.

Comment: @Opifex Incorrect. Freon is a trademark for a variety of refrigerants.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Dupont was the producer of Freon, who holds the trademark for that substance. It is now banned, so it's no longer produced. The replacement for Freon is Suva 134a.

Comment: Freon is used as a general word for any refrigerant. Strictly it is incorrect, but OK in an informal text.

Comment: @Opifex you should probably correct Wikipedia and send an email to the admins at https://freon.com - they seem to think otherwise.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It's funny you should say that, because it was Wikipedia I consulted before I wrote that previous message. Admittedly, it was a European one, not the English one. That one clearly stated that Freon is now banned.
The English one indirectly says the same. It points out that the original Freon was Dichlorodifluoromethane. If you click the link to that page, it states that its usage is banned since 1996. 
If companies wish to use an existing name for another substance, usually there's little stopping them. It can be done for commercial reasons.

Comment: @Opifex "Freon was Dichlorodifluoromethane." Incorrect. Dichlorodifluoromethane was sold as "Freon 12" Trichlorofluoromethane was sold as Freon 11. Freon is still an [active trademark](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=71321938&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch) in the US, as it has been since 1931, it has always been held by DuPont and it's fluorochemical successor Chemours.

Answer (score 10):

The compressor, along with the coils, is a sealed unit and shouldn't need to be run to keep things lubricated. Just clean it good, unplug it and keep the door cracked or you'll lock in that refrig smell. If you've got kids, disable the door lock if the refrig has one for safety reasons.

Comment: Good call. If I were going to store one I'd get a couple of chunks of foam to hold the doors open enough to keep it from getting the smell locked in, then ratchet strap it around them to keep critters and kids from getting in.

Answer (score 5):

You did not state what type or if commercial or residential. It Depends mainly on the type of compressor used. There are still many belt driven compressors that need to be run occasionally to keep the seals lubricated. The types of compressors coming out and being used is growing. It use to be a simple reciprocating, rotary, centrifugal and now rotary vane are getting very popular especially because of there smaller size. Running it every few months even though not necessary will not hurt it and it will give you a chance to be sure it is still operational.

Comment: If a business operates a belt-driven fridge compressor in 2023, chances are they also have a Chief HVAC Engineer (and a department thereof) appointed to take care of it. The replacement-in-a-hurry expenses will not be in few hundred dolar range either.